# Insert Maximo data into another database server

Tags: maximo

I want to insert some maximo data into table in another database server. I create an automation script like this

```
from psdi.security import UserInfo
from psdi.server import MXServer
from psdi.util import MXApplicationException
from psdi.util import MXException
from java.rmi import RemoteException
from java.lang import System
from java.text import Format, DateFormat, SimpleDateFormat
from java.lang import System

mx = MXServer.getMXServer();
ui = mx.getSystemUserInfo();


url= "jdbc:sqlserver://MAXIMODEMO:1433; database=IntegrationTest; user=maxadmin; password=password; encrypt=false; trustServerCertificate=false; loginTimeout=30;";

from java.lang import Class
from java.sql import DriverManager,SQLException

#load driver and register
Class.forName(jdbc_driver).newInstance()
DriverManager.registerDriver(Class.forName(jdbc_driver).newInstance())

#get Connection
#connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc_url, jdbc_user), jdbc_password)
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url)

#find if item exist
sql = "Select itemnum from item where itemnum='"+mbo.getString("ITEMNUM")+"'"
result = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(sql)

sqlinsert = ""

sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM--dd");

if(result.next()) :
    sqlinsert = "Update Item set description='"+mbo.getString("DESCRIPTION")+"', orderunit='"+mbo.getString("ORDERUNIT")+"', status='"+mbo.getString("STATUS")+"' where ItemNum='"+mbo.getString("ITEMNUM")+"'"
else:
    sqlInsert="Insert into item(itemnum, description, orderunit, statusdate, status, groupname) values('" + mbo.getString("ITEMNUM")+ "','" + mbo.getString("Description") + "', '" + mbo.getString("ORDERUNIT") + "','" + sdf.format(mbo.getDate("STATUSDATE")) + "', '" + mbo.getString("STATUS") + "','" + mbo.getString("GROUPNAME") + "') "
result.close()

result = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(sqlinsert)

connection.close()
```

There's no error but the data not inserted. the query for select is working fine, it can return the value, but the insert / update is not working.
Did I miss something in executing insert/update query?

Comment: You only need to import classes that you directly reference. So, for example, you don't need the `from psdi.security import UserInfo` because you never directly instantiate the class -- i.e. by calling `UserInfo("SOMEUSERID")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `connection.commit()` before your `connection.close()`.

Also, you should be calling `executeUpdate()` with your insert or update statement text instead of calling `executeQuery()` with it. The [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) for `java.sql.Statement.executeUpdate()` say, "Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an SQL DDL statement."

Comment: Thank you for your information. yes I wrong in that part. it should be executeUpdate instead using executeQuery.